# Sketch How to make text overrides push other text?

Tags: sketch-app

So basically what I'm trying to achieve is a basic navbar setup like so;
[image: navigation bar]

Each 'nav item' has a spacing of 80px.

This itself is a symbol which is great. However, when it comes to text overrides and renaming the 'nav items' becomes a bit of a pain.

As you can see below, it results in text overlap.
[image: nav item overlap]

I want to achieve something along the lines of;
Type something no matter how long or short, and have the padding change based on that length so that in the end, the items still have 80px padding between them.

I am aware that Sketch has this functionality ***Kind of*** built in, issue is, it seems to only apply when the padding is <= 20px (I think?).

I've tried a variety of options with no luck including;

- Using the 'Paddy' plugin to somehow keep them equally separated. This *sort of* worked but was super buggy.
- Tried using some "Button" plugins that keep a set padding. These were unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

You was trying to help someone with this earlier today, and he actually figured it out before I could even do anything haha.

So there’s a plugin from Anima that has this feature called Stacked Groups. It’s essentially flexbox within Sketch.

Here’s an article about it, and how to use it:
https://medium.com/sketch-app-sources/auto-layout-introducing-stacks-flexbox-for-sketch-c8a11422c7b5?source=linkShare-426db5aa943c-1529895926.

The one thing you have to look out for is using both the native Resizing options with Sketch, and using the stacked group’s resizing feature.

#### Chat Transcript:

> As you can see in my first screenshot i have a list of 3 items. It's a menu, where i have 2 text items (buttons) and the 3rd one with have an icon. I want to create a symbol out of these, so when I want to replace the text "item 1" with something else the whole section to resize
>   [image]
>
> I have 2 different spacing: 20px between each item (button) and 10px between item 3 and the icon
>
> I tried to create a stacked group out of all 3 items, and create a group of item 3 + icon (the box)
>   [image]
>
> but whenever i change the text with something longer, somehow all the text is pushed to the right. And i can't make it appear even if i increase the width of the symbol
>   [image]

---

Check out these two videos on Smart Resizing and Flexbox for Sketch:

- Sketch App: Resizing Options · https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VOJ_2TTOZAo&feature=youtu.be
- Flexbox for Sketch App: Stacks Auto Layout Plugin · https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DiCXg17CwIY&feature=youtu.be

---

> finally nailed it :)) apparently when stack plugin is used with the pinning option (the native one from sketch) they somehow overwrite each other.

Comment: Please don't add all these huge images with your chat history; instead transcript whatever text is needed. It makes your answer more difficult to read and unnecessarily confusing.

Comment: @Luciano - fixed!